# Log onto local machine with password manager

Tags: linux, ssh, vnc, password-management, keepass

For a while, I have been accessing my work machine through ssh/VNC so I decided to generate a random password for it with my password manager. This poses no issues since I was always accessing it through another machine where I could run keepass(x(c)).

Now I'm about to return to work on site and I was wondering how I could log onto my machine without having to type out the 35-character long (with special charaters) password. I tried investigating turning my Android phone into an USB keyboard and making it type out the password from keepass, but I couldn't find an easy way to do it without rooting the phone or some similar sorcery.

Any ideas? I still have ssh access to the machine, but I'm not sure how to remotely open a local session. The machine runs CentOS 7 with GDM as the login manager (I think?).

Comment: Easiest way would be to only use a ssh key for remote login, and have a relativly easy but secure password for local access. You can then disable password access from remote.
With this you don't have to have a 35 pass for the server, while still being on the secure side.
I know, this is not really an answer to your question, but this question sounds like a typical X-Y problem: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/348525

Comment: I can do that? How do I set separate password for ssh and for local access?

Comment: You cant have two different passwords. With this method you just skip the password alltogether when you login from remote. read up about "ssh key authentication"

Comment: Oh, that's what you meant. I know about pubkey auth, but I'm not sure how I would safely carry around my keypair in a usb stick like I do my password